Page Template slug not found after wp_insert_post
I'm trying to find out what page template slug is assigned to my newly created Wordpress page/post.
Edit: The newly created post has a custom template assigned. When creating it the error_log shows an empty string. The error_log shows the assigned template AFTER deleting the post???
Function:
function page_template_test($post_id, $post, $update) {

$template_slug = get_page_template_slug($post_id);

    if ($template_slug) {
        error_log('Template-slug found: ' . $template_slug);
    } else {
        error_log('No template-slug not found post ID: ' . $post_id);
    }

}
add_action('wp_insert_post', 'page_template_test', 10, 3);

Error Log:
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: No template-slug not found post ID: 6966; 
PHP message: No template-slug not found post ID: 6967', 
referer: https://website.org/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page


Do those posts have a different template than the default one set?

To be more explicit, per the docs, get_page_template_slug "Returns an empty string when the default page template is in use".

I've assigned a template called 'Product', filename 'product-page.php'. It still returns an empty string.

Have you confirmed if $template_slug is an empty string, null or false? You said the former in the comment, but the code doesn't reflect that.

New error_log: 'PHP message: Is set to FALSE'

I think that happens because the post doesn't full exist yet. Try bypassing the function and just call $template_slug = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true )

I've also tried this method, but it gives me the same result.
